# PGSQL error when trying to add constraint to perfom upsert after

Tags: postgresql, key, constraints, upsert

I can't create an unique constraint on my table and don't understand why, since I try to use an upsert it said to me that I can't do it because I don't have constraint on table. So I tried this :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_ID" ON "WU_MatchingUsers" ("IDWU_User1");
ERREUR:  n'a pas pu créer l'index unique « unique_ID »
DÉTAIL : La clé ("IDWU_User1")=(1) est dupliquée.
```

I don't understand why and don't know what to do.

Kind Regards !

Comment: it means you already have some duplicates (with `DWU_User1 = 1`), so you can't create a unique index. --> fix the duplicate values first

Comment: What you mean by duplicated ? I checked my TABLE and ther is only one "1" in this column :/

Comment: The database says otherwise, and I believe it more than I believe your claim.